# How to get the toast from Spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm having some issues getting a toast message and Spinner selected text is also not being set to the spinner. Below is the code that isn't working.

```
category_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                showMessage("Selected "+position+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

public void showMessage(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` if you are using the method inside an Activity.

Comment: Try `Activity.getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `getApplicationContext()` with `Activity.this`, like this:

```
 Toast.makeText(Activity.this,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: are you sure that `onItemSelected` is even getting called? put Log in there and check